# "fall prey to" or "fall a prey to"

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

Thanks everyone for checking this question.

I was reading *Great Books of the Western World*, and there is a phrase "fall a prey to" and since I didn't know about it so I went to Collins Dict and Google, but all I've got is the phrase "fall prey to" instead of what was in the book.

I was confused. So this time I searched on some Chinese-English Dicts cuz I'm Chinese. OK now there it is - "fall a prey to"!

I turned out to be utterly confused.

Here's the original text from the book:

> We believe that the reduction of the citizen to an object of propaganda, private and public, is one of the greatest dangers to democracy. A prevalent notion is that the great mass of the people cannot understand and cannot form an independent judgment upon any matter; they cannot be educated, in the sense of developing their intellectual powers, but they can be bamboozled. The reiteration of slogans, the distortion of the news, the great storm of propaganda that beats upon the citizen twenty-four hours a day all his life long mean *either that democracy must **fall a prey to*** the loudest and most persistent propagandists or that the people must save themselves by strengthening their minds so that they can ap- praise the issues for themselves.

Thanks again for everyone's patience and help here.

Comment: ***Fall prey to*** is the more common version, ***fall a prey to*** is now a less common variant: see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall+prey+to%2Cfall+a+prey+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20prey%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20a%20prey%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you @user240918 ! It's no wonder why Mr Hutchins wrote it as "fall a prey to" in the book cuz the set I read was published in 1950s. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: The 1950s is not so long ago at all in terms of linguistic drift.

Comment: Yes @tchrist I agree. I merely referred to the diagram showed on that website above.